# Eclipse eGit on Linux screwing line endings

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

Because of the changes in line endings, commits looks a lot bigger than they should be.

I have egit 4.6.1.201703071140

Before using egit, the command

```
git ls-files --eol
```

shows

```
i/mixed w/mixed attr/                   somefile
```

then, after commit in Eclipse via git staging view, it is:

```
i/lf    w/mixed attr/                   somefile
```

Another example:

```
i/crlf  w/crlf  attr/                   somefile2
```

becomes:

```
 i/lf    w/crlf  attr/                   somefile2
```

You can see egit is changing the first column to i/lf.

In GitHub you can use ?w=1 to dampen the noise, but how do I fix the problem itself?

**git config**

```
core.autocrlf=input
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.logallrefupdates=true
remote.origin.url=https://github.com/plutext/docx4j.git
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
branch.master.remote=origin
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
branch.master.rebase=false
```

Comment: What kind of actions are you doing with the file? What are your git configurations for that repository (`git config -l`)?

Comment: i've added the config above.  In the git staging view, I just "add to index" then "commit", or "commit and push" - nothing fancy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration:

> You can tell Git to **convert CRLF to LF on commit** but not the other way around by setting `core.autocrlf` to `input`.

You probably want to use `false` instead.

Comment: Turns out there are still some issues .. i/lf    w/crlf becomes i/mixed w/crlf, maybe because of using Eclipse "Compare with Index" then copying change from right to left.